# posts_per_page returning only one post

Tags: posts, wp-query

```
function blog_post_home_shortcode() {
  $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => ' publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ));

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
      $blog = get_the_title();
  return $blog;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('blogs_home', 'blog_post_home_shortcode');
```

returns only one title while in WP_Query I have set `posts_per_page => 3` I want to display all 3 title of last published posts.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Setting `posts_per_page ` to `3` should show 3 posts. If `-1` (unlimited) is only showing 1, then you only have 1 published post, or another plugin is interfering with your query.

Comment: I have 13 posts Published but only one shows even when I put `posts_per_page => -1`

Comment: Why do you have `return` statement inside while loop?

Comment: I am creating a shortcode using functions.php so that's why I have to return

Comment: You're returning inside the loop, so it's only ever going to output one post.

Comment: You cannot have a return statement inside a function with a loop. This will stop the execution of the `for/while/do...` and return the current `title`

Comment: I have updated my code with function for adding shortcode @JacobPeattie

Comment: You're not understanding how return works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may please update your code as follows

```
   function blog_post_home_shortcode() {
  $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => ' publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ));

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
      $blog = get_the_title();
  echo $blog;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('blogs_home', 'blog_post_home_shortcode');
```

Please check the above code and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This shortcode is echoing its output, meaning it won't appear in the correct place. Shortcodes need to use return (but not inside a loop).

Comment: @JacobPeattie then where should I put return? The Code given by Pratik is working well for my output

Comment: You need to either build up a variable by concatenating it during the loop, or output buffering. See my answer.

Comment: @jacob it is not necessary to have a return in your function. In this case it was not required so he have not used it.

Comment: @Jumper Yes, return is required. See documentation for the shortcode API. `echo` will work in some contexts, but it's still incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcodes need to `return` their output, otherwise the output will appear whenever the content that contains it is processed, rather than where inside the content the shortcode actually appears.

The simplest way to achieve this is to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the output with `ob_start()` and then return what it captured with `ob_get_clean()`:

```
function blog_post_home_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_status'    => ' publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    ) );

    while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'blogs_home', 'blog_post_home_shortcode' );
```

See [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for more (emphasis mine):

> The return value of a shortcode handler function is inserted into the
>   post content output in place of the shortcode macro. **Remember to use
>   return and not echo** - anything that is echoed will be output to the
>   browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.